# add px using es6 in JSX failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do this in my loop, `i` is my index

```
let bars = 100

style={{top: `${i * bars}`}
```

but got warning `was passed a numeric string value for CSS property`width`(value:`250`) which will be treated as a unitless number in a future`

How do I add px?

I tried

```
style={{top: `${i * bars}px`}
```

it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried the simplest way  : `style={{top: (i * bars) + 'px'}}`

Comment: What didn't work about that attempt? It looks fine.

Comment: Try console logging (i * bars) and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't work

It works fine. Demonstrated below:

[image]

## More Tips

Most likely `i` is not what you think it is. Try logging it.